# Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2/(n^2 + n) = 1$ using $\epsilon-N$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I would like someone to verify my $\epsilon-N$ proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n^2}{n^2 + n}$ = 1.

**Proof**:

Let $\epsilon > 0 $, and choose $N = \lceil1/\epsilon\rceil + 1$. Then for all $n > N$, we have

$$\left|\frac{n^2}{n^2 + n} - 1 \right| = \left|\frac{-n}{n^2 + n}\right| = \frac{n}{n^2 + n} \leq \frac{n}{n^2} = 1/n.$$

But since we have $n > N =  \lceil1/\epsilon\rceil + 1 > \lceil1/\epsilon\rceil \geq 1/\epsilon$, it follows that $\epsilon > 1/n$. Thus, $1/n < \epsilon$ as we desired to show. Therefore, we conclude that the limit equals $1$.

Comment: That's fine. A minor quibble: you could have taken $N = \left\lfloor1/\epsilon\right\rfloor$, so $N + 1 > 1/\epsilon$, and if $n \geqslant N$ then $n/(n^2 + n) = 1/(n + 1) \leqslant 1/(N + 1) < \epsilon$.

Comment: That's fine.  But there is absolutely no reason to waste a single brain cell in trying to figure out what $N$ is.  Simply saying "Let $N \ge \frac 1{\epsilon}$ then for all $n > N$" is good enough.  And it makes the proof *easier* to follow.  The precise value of $N$ or even that $N$ is an integer is of absolute *NO* importance or significance.  So don't waste *ANY* time trying to figure it out.  Life's too short for that.

Comment: @fleablood I heard you the first time! But life's too short to argue about it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. But another approach could be:

Let $\epsilon>0$. For the archimedean property there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such as, $$\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon.$$ Let $n\geq N$, then, $$\left|\dfrac{n^2}{n^2+n}-1\right|=\dfrac{n}{n^2+n}\leq \dfrac{1}{n}\leq \dfrac{1}{N}<\epsilon$$ So, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n}{n^2+n}=1.$$

Comment: Is that significantly different than what the OP did?

Comment: Although I do agree with you. I have said it before and I'll say it again one really should not waste *any* brain power in figure out what is the smallest possible integer value that $N$ can be.  That is of *zero* importance.  All we want is that you choose $n$ so that $n > \frac 1{\epsilon}$.  Just what the absolute lowest possible integer that satisfies that is not of *ANY* importance.  So why waste *any* time figuring it out? ... that is.  We don't *care* that $N=\lceil\frac 1\epsilon\rceil +1$.  We *only* care that $N \ge \frac 1{\epsilon}$.

Comment: @fleablood well OP did searched for smallest value, while here we only invoke archimedian property, to say there exists such an N, so it is going in your direction. I don't understand your comment...

Comment: @fleablood Oops. :)

Comment: "well OP did searched for smallest value"  But why????  What possible use is it?  And where did the OP get the idea that $N$ should be an integer?  As far as proving this just say "for any natural number $n > \frac 1 \epsilon$..."  and that's it.  If we need to follow the definition we can say "any value equal or larger than $\frac 1\epsilon$ will satisfy the $N$ in the definition".  It just seem picayune to fuss about an exact integer value.

Comment: let there be upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{n}{n^2+n}=\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
Since
$$
\frac{1}{n+1}<\varepsilon
$$
if and only if
$$
n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1
$$
you can just take $N=\lceil \varepsilon^{-1}-1\rceil$ (least integer greater than or equal to $\varepsilon^{-1}-1$), which exists by the Archimedean property.

Of course, any integer $N>1/\varepsilon$ would do as well.